# Why does my loop work when printing the values, but not when adding them to a list?

Tags: java, list

```
List<String> fileNames; 
   void fileList(final File folder) {
        for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()){
                if(fileEntry.isDirectory()){
                    fileList(fileEntry);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println(fileEntry.getName());
                    //fileNames.add(fileEntry.getName());
                }            
            }
        }
    }
```

In this loop, I've attempted to read every file in the directory "folder" and add it to a list of Strings for later use. These fileNames will be put into another method later, so I needed it in a string format, but for some reason (most likely my oblivious entry level coding skills) I cannot get the loop to add them to a list without getting n exception. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You should provide the Exception you are getting (probably a NullPointerException) and the stack trace. The reason is that `fileNames` is not instantiated. Change the line to `List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `fileNames` is `null` (you never *initialize* it). Change

```
List<String> fileNames;
```

to

```
List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Thank you so much!